# How to fix the IIS Error (PUT method not allowed)

Tags: angular, iis, server, put

I have developed a Angular Universal app for server side rendering. I have to save a file in server. The file get saved in the folder in  angular app. When I build the app and add it to the IIS server, I am not able to upload the file in the directory. I get the error PUT Method not allowed.Any help would be great!

> polyfills-es2015.99fc5dde03f2933ff53f.js:1 PUT http://localhost:99/files 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the WebDAV module intercepted the request.

you could try to add the below code in your site web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>        
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>        
    <remove name="WebDAV" />    
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done this part, but still I get the error.

Comment: @JenyAugustineJoseph try to set the allow vert put by adding this code in config file: `<system.webServer><security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
                <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
            </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>`